# basic Authorization - SSL Handshake failed

Tags: swift, ssl, https

Trying to connect to a webservice over https with basic authorization, however i cant get it to work. The error message i get: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806). Appreciate your help. Here is the relevant code:

```
            var post : NSString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"
        let postData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let base64EncodedCredential = postData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)



        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

        var url : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://localhost:8080/webservice")!

        var postLength : NSString = String( base64EncodedCredential.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) )

        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
        let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        urlConnection!.start()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914248/ios-8-has-broken-ssl-connection-in-my-app-cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-9806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Basic Authorization, since this is done after the successful SSL handshake. Based on your URL of `https://localhost:8080` I would suggest that you have at least one of the following problems, but maybe several:

- No HTTPS spoken, but plain HTTP. Port 8080 is very unusual for HTTPS, but often used with HTTP.
- Name in the certificate does not match name in the URL (`localhost`).
- Certificate is not signed by an authority trusted by the client.

I recommend to check the URL with a browser to find about more about the issue.

Comment: Yeah it seems when i changed it to https the port changed to 8181. Thanks!